# Load and parse json from server into HStack on launch

Tags: json, swift, arraylist, swiftui, hstack

Is it possible to get an HStack to load a json file with an image and title into a view that when tapped loads the linked video into a default player, without using list? I've accomplished this with List however I can not seem to find a way to create a usable Horizontal view.

Current list code:

```
struct VideoList: View {
    @ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State private var isRefreshing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.videos.sorted { $0.id > $1.id}, id: \.id) { video in
                NavigationLink(
                destination: VideoDetails(viewModel: VideoDetails.ViewModel(video: video))) {
                    VideoRow(video: video)
                    }
            }
            .onPullToRefresh(isRefreshing: $isRefreshing, perform: {
                self.viewModel.fetchVideos()
            })
            .onReceive(viewModel.$videos, perform: { _ in
                self.isRefreshing = false
            })
            .navigationBarTitle(viewModel.navigationBarTitle)
              }
        .onAppear(perform: viewModel.fetchVideos)
    }
}
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "videos": [
        {
            "id": 87,
            "name": "Title 2",
            "thumbnail": "https://videodelivery.net/,
            "video_link": "https://videodelivery.net/"
        },
        {
            "id": 86,
            "name": "Title one",
            "thumbnail": "https://videodelivery.net/",
            "video_link": "https://videodelivery.net/"
        }
    ]
    "videos section 2": [
        {
            "id": 52,
            "name": "Title 2",
            "thumbnail": "https://videodelivery.net/,
            "video_link": "https://videodelivery.net/"
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Title one",
            "thumbnail": "https://videodelivery.net/",
            "video_link": "https://videodelivery.net/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please explain more: should this HStack be scrollable? Which iOS are you using?

Comment: Hey @pawello2222 ! Yes iOS 14... I'm open to other ways to do this as well (less code bloat if possible) essentially think Netflix but I'm also interested in eventually dropping the video view and just having it load the video in the default player. The main premise is getting the view to load a horizontal list with the video image and title, then linking.

Comment: Then I recommend you take a look at `LazyHGrid` or `LazyHStack` (and possibly wrap them in a `ScrollView`).

Comment: @pawello2222 are there any examples or explanations using json remotely? as I've found it hard to get anything to autoload upon being viewable. it seems as if List functionality such as loading async isn't possible.

Comment: *upon being viewable* - can be run in `onAppear`. *loading async isn't possible* - this is why I recommend LazyHStack instead of HStack.

Comment: ah that makes sense... do you by chance have any documentation to link to @pawello2222

Comment: Just type *swiftui lazyhstack* in google - [LazyHStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyhstack). You can also see this tutorial: [SwiftUI: Lazy Grids and Stacks](https://medium.com/dev-genius/swiftui-lazy-grids-and-stacks-8b5cdacc7c19)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221591/discussion-between-realtechygod-and-pawello2222).